# Calculating adjacent side of triangle in java?

Tags: java, android, trigonometry

I am working on an application that can calculate how far a ladder has to be from the wall in this case the ladder is the hypotenuse and the value of that will vary on the users input so it will be calculated in feet , X = 73 degrees, A = cos 73 Adjacent/Hypotenuse. Check the bellow image to understand better:

[image]

I did some research and I found out the distance between the rungs on a ladder are about 1 feet, the user would have to count the number of rungs and input that number to the `EditText` and press the button to calculate the results while displaying it using Toast.
SO how would I be able to calculate A using trigonometric functions in java and how would I be able to convert the strings from `EditText` to a double please help me figure this out am working on a school project here is my code so far, please tell me what I have to add or remove thank you for your time kind of new to this!
Also I have manually converted A to radians since I do not know how to convert degrees to radians also!

```
package com.ladder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.widget.EditText; 
import android.widget.Toast;  
import java.lang.Math;

public class LadderActivity extends Activity {  double x;
    double r = Math.cos(1.274090354);

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

            EditText edt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
            String k = edt1.toString();


        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
         btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " FT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            }       });
    } }
```

Comment: *I do not know how to convert degrees to radians also*. I'm sure your friendly neighbourhood search engine would be able to answer that much faster than us.  Doesn't seem like you're giving it too much effort.

Comment: You're doing trigonometry and can't convert degrees to radians? A full circle is 360°. It's also 2 * pi. Now you just have to make a division.

Comment: Ok how would Use trig function in java

Comment: Your code already uses `Math.cos()`. Read its javadoc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Math class of java and below is detailed answer of your question 
**Convert string from Edittext to double**

```
    //Your editText
    EditText editText = null;
    //Convert editText value to double.
    String stringValue = editText.getText().toString();
    Double doubleValue = 0.0;
    try{
        doubleValue = Double.parseDouble(stringValue);
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**How to convert Degree into radian**

```
        double angleInDegrees = 189.0;// angle in degree
        double angleInRadians = angleInDegrees * Math.PI / 180.0;
```

These are sides of triangle

```
double Hypotenuse, Opposite, Adjacent;
```

**Calculate 'Adjacent' Value.**

```
        double angleInDegrees = (double)73;// angle in degree
        double angleInRadians = angleInDegrees * Math.PI / 180.0;

        double Adjacent = Math.cos(angleInRadians) * Hypotenuse          
        OR
        double Adjacent = Math.tan(angleInRadians)* Opposite
```

**Calculate Opposite Value**

```
        Opposite = Math.sin(angleInRadians)* Hypotenuse;
        Opposite = Math.tan(angleInRadians)*Adjacent;
```

**Calculate Hypotenuse Value**

```
        Hypotenuse = Opposite/Math.sin(angleInRadians);
        Hypotenuse = Adjacent/Math.cos(angleInRadians);
```